# Create list of jQuery elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some jquery elements:

```
var elem1 = $("#elem1");
var elem2 = $("#elem2");
var elem3 = $("#elem3");
```

I need to create a jquery array (list) of these elements, just like having

```
var allElements = $("#container").children("div");
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method which adds elements to the set of matched elements.

```
var allElements = elem1.add(elem2).add(elem3);
```

Comment: It is faster than creating an array. See my benchmark at http://jsperf.com/create-list-of-jquery-dom-objects

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me :

```
var allElements = [];
$("#container > div").each(function(){
    allElements.push($(this));
});
```

1st create the array, then push each div child of your container in this array.

```
both $("#container > div") and $("#container").children("div") work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all in to an instance of Array(). jquery is a totally new face of javascript. with lots of added features for better web designs.
If you intend to apply different effects on different #elements, I'd better say no, because you may then need to process/access each element for that job. Thus the performance issue.

Comment: It doesn't work, because i tried var array[] = [ elem1, elem2, elem3 ] But is not a jquery array (it doesn't have addClass() for example)

Comment: I need something like: jqueryList = $.list([ elem1, elem2, elem3 ]); jqueryList.addClass("selected")

Comment: @RaraituL You need `.add` method. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

 var arr = new Array($('#el1'),$('#el2'), $('#el3'));
 alert( arr.length );

});
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYhU3/)

Comment: that's because you need to specify the element in the array that will receive the class, or iterate to change the class to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

var array = [ $("elem1"), $("elem2"), $("elem2") ];

work?

Comment: Would not make a jquery array :(